# how to change knob's image of Jslider on mouseover and mouse pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I need to change knob's image of Jslider on mouse over and mouse pressed over it.

Please tell me how can i do this.

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: This is your 4th posting on this topic. You never bother to reply when you get a suggestion. You never bother to post a SSCCE. I've made an effort on two previous questions but I won't be fooled this time into help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `MouseListener` and handle the mouse pressed/released events, and mouse entered/exited events.  For the pressed/entered events change your component as desired, and for released/exited, change it back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i have done the coding as mentioned n this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042527/how-to-put-an-image-over-jsliders-knob-image-when-mouse-is-present-over-the-knob. But onmouseover there is no change on knob's image. Could you please explain with some code snippet.